# Add element to Json within JArray

Tags: c#, .net, json, linq, json.net

I have been trying to add an element into a JArrays JToken when a condition is met. What I am trying to achieve is something like the below. However, below, the add statement does not compile but conveys what I need to try and do. Anyone know how to do this?

```
        string json = @"[
        {""1"":""One"",""2"":""AddThree""},
        {""1"":""One"",""2"":""Two""},
        {""1"":""One"",""2"":""AddThree""}
        ]";

        JArray rows = JArray.Parse(json);
        int length = rows.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            string s = rows[i]["2"].ToString();
            if (s == "AddThree")
            {
                //This functionality doesnt exist
                rows[i].Children().ADD(@"""3"":""Three""");
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(rows.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Looking at this in the cold light of morning... I just remembered that JSON will create an element upon setting it so: var row = rows[i]; row["3"] = "Three"; inside the 'if' statement does the job, strange behaviour but it works so good enough for me.

Comment: Interesting.. Do you mean to say `row["3"] = "Three"` adds a Json string to the Jarray rows?

I thought the solution will be using [JArray.Add](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray_Add.htm)

Comment: I can't mark as the answer until tomorrow but I've added the solution below, and yes, `row["3"] = "Three"` adds `"3": "Three"` to the token contained within the current jarray item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json will create the element upon setting it if the element did not already exist.

```
    string json = @"[
    {""1"":""One"",""2"":""AddThree""},
    {""1"":""One"",""2"":""Two""},
    {""1"":""One"",""2"":""AddThree""}
    ]";

    JArray rows = JArray.Parse(json);
    foreach (var row in rows)
    {
        string s = row["2"].ToString();
        if (s == "AddThree")
        {
            row["3"] = "Three";
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(rows.ToString());
    Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if this works?

Change `rows[i].Children().ADD(@"""3"":""Three""");` to

`rows[i].Children().Add(JToken.Parse(@"""3"":""Three"""));`

Comment: Sorry, Children() doesn't have an .Add method. I found the solution earlier. See my comment above if your interested.